# Adding padding to the left of text in buffer

Tags: linum-mode, fringe

I have been looking around for some fix for this but I cannot google-fu my way out of it. I have tried setting the fringe, but that doesn't seem to work. Right now I have the code

```
(unless (bound-and-true-p linum-mode)
  (setq left-fringe-width 10))
```

To give my text some space to the left of the edge of the buffer when `linum-mode` isn't enabled. This is because with `neo-tree` active its hard to see the edge of the text sometimes, and the text is pressed right up against the edge of the window. However, this doesn't seem to work. Is there a better method to do this? I am using console Emacs.

Thanks!

Comment: The question is unclear. Try giving a step-by-step recipe or showing a screenshot or something. It's not clear what you want and why (in what way), in particular, a left fringe does *not* give you what you want.

Comment: I guess `left-fringe-width` won't work in text mode. I think it is a X11 thing. It is measured in pixels. But, maybe I am underestimating the capabilities of the console...

Comment: Looks like my guess was right. The section on "fringes" in the emacs-info-manual starts with "On **graphical** displays, Emacs draws fringes next to each window".

Comment: I think the following link answers your question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7251784/how-do-i-adjust-the-left-margin-in-emacs-nox

Comment: @Tobias Seems to be what im looking for. Post this as an answer so I can give you credit.

Comment: I posted the answer. Actually, I wanted to mark the question as duplicate. But, this is not possible since the answer is from stackoverflow.com and not from emacs.stackexchange.com. Marking the answer as solution is good since this indicates the question as answered. (Credit is secondary.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7251784/how-do-i-adjust-the-left-margin-in-emacs-nox:

> `(set-window-margins nil 1)` will instantly give a left margin of one
>   char to the current window (that's the nil)

Answer (score 0):

(set-fringe-mode 14)

or more precisely

(set-window-fringes (selected-window) 14 0)

or

(setq-default left-margin-width 14 right-margin-width 14)